# PHP does not work on alias (XAMPP)

Tags: php, windows, apache-http-server, xampp, alias

I trying to make alias on my local machine with XAMPP for my PHP project.

I added follow in httpd.conf:

```
Include "conf/alias/*"
```

And make two files for aliases, one of them is like:

```
Alias /aiuu "d:/projects/ibuu/trunk/pbs"
<Directory "d:/projects/ibuu/trunk/pbs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I can access on path localhost/aiuu, but php does not work, only html.

Where i made mistake?

Comment: Have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408/make-xampp-apache-serve-file-outside-of-htdocs

Comment: Yes, I did all for Alias setting, but without succes :(